# Auto type from html page to windows application

Tags: javascript, php, windows

I have a javascript+php web application that process and produce some data.
Imagine that at the end I have something like an array of values.

My need is to pass these values to a windows application to auto populate the fields of a form in the windows application.

The idea is that the user:

1. open the windows application and open the form with fields.
2. Go the the web application using a browser like Chrome and process
   data to produce array of values
3. From the web application click a "Auto populate" button, and the
   system get the values and use them to autopoulate the form fields of
   the windows application.

Have someone some suggestions on how to built such a behaviour?
Is this possible in some way?

Please help me to go to the right way.

With Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Your best (only?) option is Sockets for long polling server for user input. Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not enough to comment so I am writing it as an answer.

Your meaning is autocomplete?

If yes, you can see this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/